# If every subring of $S$ containing $v\in S$ is ring-finite over $R,$ is $v$ necessarily integral over $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-extensions

In the following, $R$ is a subring of a ring $S,$ and $v\in S.$ All of my rings are commutative with $1.$

I like to use the following terminology.

**Definitions.** I say that $S$ is **module-finite** over $R$ if there is a surjective $R$-module homomorphism $R^{\oplus n}\to S$ for some $n$, and I say that $S$ is **ring-finite** over $R$ if there is a surjective ring homomorphism $R[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}]\to S$ for some $n$.

It seems that most people prefer other terminology. To make sure everyone is on the same page:

- module-finite over $R$ implies ring-finite over $R,$ but the converse does not hold.
- "integral + ring-finite = module-finite", i.e., $S$ is integral over $R$ and ring-finite over $R$ if and only if $S$ is module-finite over $R.$

I feel that the answer to the following question is "no", but I'm not sure how to go about looking for a counterexample.

> **Question.** Suppose every subring $R^{\prime}$ of $S$ with $R[v]\subseteq R^{\prime}$ is ring-finite over $R.$ Does this imply that $v$ is integral over $R$?
>
> **Equivalent question.** Suppose every subring $R^{\prime}$ of $S$ with $R[v]\subseteq R^{\prime}$ is ring-finite over $R.$ Does this imply that $R[v]$ is module-finite over $R$?

To be clear: the answer is "no" if there exists a triple $(R,S,v)$ as above such that $v$ is not integral over $R$ but whenever $R[v]\subseteq R^{\prime}\subseteq S$ is an intermediate ring then $R^{\prime}$ is ring-finite over $R.$

Comment: I guess everywhere you say "ring" after the first sentence you really mean "$R$-algebra"?

Comment: @EricWofsey: Ah, good point, I mean that $R\subset R^{\prime},$ so the answer to your question is yes. I'll edit the post to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Indeed, take *any* example of a non-integral element $v$ over $R$ in some $R$-algebra and let $S$ be the subalgebra generated by $v$.  Then the only choice of $R'$ is $S$ itself, which is ring-finite over $R$.

Comment: I had a funny feeling I was just getting confused by all of the quantifiers. Turns out I was right! Thanks for the quick response.